# Why is "Zeile" but not "Zeiger" differently pronounced in the south?

Tags: etymology, dialect, pronunciation, standard-german

For both nouns there is a similar pronunciation of *"-ei-"* in standard German:

> Zeile: **[ˈʦaɪ̯lə]**
>   Zeiger: **[ˈʦaɪ̯ɡɐ]**

When people in some southern German regions try to speak non-dialect German the pronunciation of *"-ei-*" is different for "*Zeile*" (**[ˈʦeɪ̯lə]**] only but not for *"Zeiger"* which is likely to be pronounced according to standard German. I can speak mainly for Swabian dialects but some other regions may pronounce this similarly (see *"Zeile"* in [Wiktionary](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/De-at-Zeile.ogg) for Austria)

Many other words (e.g. *Eis, Weiß* (color)*, beißen* [**eɪ̯**] vs. *Bein, weiß (wissen), Reim* [**aɪ̯**]) also show this phenomenon.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: The vowel bifurcates in Yiddish and I can give you a list of words in each category, but it almost looks like the opposite of what you're showing here? You haven't clarified in your list of six examples which are ai and which are ei...in Yiddish it woud be ays, vays, and baisen (same as standard German) vs. beyn and veys, where the vowel shifts.. I hope my phonetic spelling is self-explanatory.

Comment: I have to admit that while living in the south of Germany (Rhein-Neckar Raum) I'm not aware of the phenomenon you are describing. Can you tell more precisely in which region of Germany this can be observed?

Comment: Which regions do you mean exactly?  "some southern German regions" is quite vague.

Comment: That's wierd. I always assumed that the vowel shift was a residue of an obsolete German usage which somehow later merged. I don't see how it would actually flip over. Any more examples I could check against?

Comment: In Yiddish we have "tsayt" and "zeyger" (rhymes with "height" and "flavor". Opposites again? (BTW a "zeyger" is a wristwatch; it's a very rare case of the German z going over to a hard-s in Yiddish.)

Comment: I don't live in southern Germany, but I've also never heard this from southerners. Are you sure it's a southern German thing, and not an idiosyncracy from some of the people you know, or residue of a dialect they've brought with them when they moved to the south?

Comment: In der zweiten Hälfte dieser Seite stehen ein paar interessante Sachen (leider zu wenig für eine Antwort): http://books.google.it/books?id=9YgXPlPY7rAC&pg=PA624&lpg=PA624&dq=diphthonge+im+Wienerischen&source=bl&ots=P_IVlvDp3-&sig=nR8pBDYLSXQB-KdTqCWy4A_6xxo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Y93tTo-7NYqB4gSzvtmfCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=diphthonge%20im%20Wienerischen&f=false

Comment: @Takkat ja, das Buch ist selbst wäre eine kleine Sprachanalyse wert. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Werner Besch schreibt in seinem Buch *Sprachgeschichte: ein Handbuch zur Geschichte der deutschen Sprache und ihrer Erforschung*:

> Ein Kennlautung des heutigen Wienerischen ist [a]
>   für mhd. *ei* ([ha:s] 'heiß'), die sich auch in den
>   mbair. Umgangssprachen Österreichs zunehmend
>   durchsetzt, Kranzmayer ([1956, § 20g2) hielt dieses
>   [a] für eine Folge der "Verschweizerung" des Wiener
>   Hofes unter den ersten Habsburgern Rudolf und
>   Albrecht Ende des 1. Jhs. Tatsächlich gilt (heute)
>   in der Nordostschweiz (Thurgau, Appenzell, z. T.
>   St. Galle) [a, ä] für mhd. *ei*. Aber die Habsburg
>   liegt nicht im Thurgau, sondern im Aargau, wo [ay]
>   für *ei* gilt, und es ist völlig unterwiesen, dass
>   Rudolf sein Gefolge aus der "Ostschweiz" mitbrachte
>   (so Kranzmayer). [...]
>
> Viel plausibler ist m. E. die Pfalz' Erklärung, [a] 
>   stamme aus der mittelmährischen Verkehrssprache des 16. Jhs., einer Ausgleichsprache
>   mit bair. und md. Zügen (anders Wiesinger 2001).

Vermutlich hängt die unterschiedliche Aussprache des Diphthongs davon ab, woher (aus welcher Zeit und Kultur) die entsprechenden Wörter stammen oder übernommen wurde.

Comment: The passage you mention speculates about the question why Middle High German *ei* became [a] in Vienna. It is not at all about the difference between the sounds that derive from Middle High German *ei* and Middle High German *ī.*

Answer (score 10):

The *ei* diphtong are in *Zeile* and *Zeiger* derived from two different middle-high-german sounds:

- *Hd.* Zeiger = *mhd* [zeiger](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Zeiger)
- *Hd.* Zeile = *mhd* [zīl(e)](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Zeiger)

For the modern high-german, the *ei* remained the same, whereas *ī* morphed into *ei*.

In the southern dialects (e.g. Bairisch, Schweizerdeutsch), this was different:

- In Schweizerdeutsch, the vocals [remained basically the same](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schweizerdeutsch#Bewahrung_der_mittelhochdeutschen_Monophthonge) (hence *Schwiizerdütsch*)
- In Bairisch, [*ī* morphed into *ei*, and *ei* morphed into *oa*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairische_Dialekte#Historischer_Exkurs%3a_altes_vs._junges_ei) (or *aa* in the Viennese variant).

Comment: Is there a list where I can see which words had which vowel in MHG?

Comment: Das scheint auf den ersten Blick sehr einleuchtend (ī -> [eɪ̯] und ei -> [aɪ̯]) und trifft bei obigen Beispielen auch, aber schon hier bei *scheinen* (schwäb. **[ˈʃaɪ̯nən]**) aus mhd. *schīnen* geht das nicht mehr auf. Die Diphthongierung wird ja vollzogen, nur mit anderer Betonung als im Hochdeutschen.

Comment: @Takkat könnte das vielleicht eine Kontamination durch etwas anderes sein? Im Bairischen ist der Lautwandel ja auch für Wörter im Gottesdienst-Gebraucht nicht vollzogen.

Comment: Guter Gedanke, es gibt da schon gewisse Variationen (z.B. *Lehrer*) in evangelischen und katholischen Regionen (das wäre fast eine neue Frage wert!).

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to compile words with "ei" that are pronounced "ah" vs. "ei" in Vienna:

ah:
Zeiger
weich
Beine
meinen (verb)
keine
eine
weiß (verb)

ei:
Zeit
weit
Weile
Zeile
Teil
feilen
fein
mein (possessive)
Heiterkeit
weiß (color)
Reim
neigen
Leiche

Several remarks:
1. Words that have foreign etymology are not modified to "ah".
2. If "ei" is followed by t/d/m/l, I have not found an example where it is pronounced "ah".
3. Different pronounciation is obviously used to distinguish synonyms.
4. I do think that the etymology of the vowels would explain a lot of the differences (compare the adjective "weiß" corresponding to "white" and the verb "weiß" corresponding to "wit").

I can say more when I am near my dictionaries again.

Comment: I am REALLY not understanding your phonetics anymore. Are you saying now Zeiger rhymes with blogger and zeit rhymes with tight, or what?

Comment: I am talking about Viennese dialect, as the title has some claims on Southern dialect. This will not be the same pronounciation as in, say, Yiddish, but I am very sure that the distinction between words will be the same. And I don't know how you pronounce blogger (not very useful to choose a word that cannot be looked up in dictionaries), but it will certainly not rhyme. The vowel in "Zeiger" in Vienna will be a long "ah" similar to "market". But you are *wrong* to think that vowels in one language exist in the other. "Tight" will give a close approximation to "Zeit", yes.

Comment: I still don't get it. I'm looking at what Takkat wrote earlier: "Zeit is 'ei' in Swabian even though it shares the same etymology as Zeiger ('ai')". I'm undertanding from him that Zeit rhymes with plate and Zeiger rhymes with Tiger. From you I'm understanding that Zeiger rhymes very approximately with bugger and Zeit with tight...isn't this very different from what Takkat said?

Comment: So you guys are talking about two different regional dialects?

Comment: @MartyGreen Since Austria was mentioned, I explained how this distinction works in Austria. I know nothing about Swabian dialects and my post is supposed to be the most helpful way possible to explain that the hypotheses of the OP are not correct.